# How can I fix this html table

Tags: html

I think My html code is messed up and I can't fix it.I he been workin on for 2 hours
this is the output
[image]

Please can you help me

```
    <?php
   if($_POST){
   }
    else{
      echo '
   <form action="" method="post">
   <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
   <td>Ad</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="ad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Posta</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="posta"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Mesaj</td>
    <td><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="mesaj"</textarea>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Gonder"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    ';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: the closing `>` of your `<textarea>` element is missing and causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>Ad</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="ad">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Posta</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="posta">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mesaj</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="mesaj"> </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Gonder">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

You forgot to close the textarea tag and the td its in, also please use some indentation. it hurts my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>` Missing '>' For End Of Tag (At line 13, column 9)

it should be

```
   <form action="" method="post">
   <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
   <td>Ad</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="ad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Posta</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="posta"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Mesaj</td>
    <td><textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="mesaj"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Gonder"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the td the textarea its in

Comment: @ErnestoMayoralCabezas Ya! Thank you.